# Back propagation algorithm gets stuck on training AND function

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Here is an implementation of AND function with single neuron using tensorflow:

```
def tf_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-x))

data = [
    (0, 0),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 1),
]

labels = [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
]

n_steps = 1000
learning_rate = .1

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=None)

w = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[2], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)

h = tf.reduce_sum(x * w) + b
output = tf_sigmoid(h)

error = tf.abs(output - y)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())


for step in range(n_steps):
    for i in np.random.permutation(range(len(data))):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: data[i], y: labels[i]})
```

Sometimes it works perfectly, but on some parameters it gets stuck and doesn't want to learn. For example with these initial parameters:

```
w = tf.Variable(initial_value=[-0.31199348, -0.46391705], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=-1.94877, dtype=tf.float32)
```

it will hardly make any improvement in cost function. What am I doing wrong, maybe I should somehow adjust initialization of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing a `mean(error)` ?

Your problem is the particular combination of the sigmoid, the cost function, and the optimizer.

Don't feel bad, AFAIK this exact problem stalled the *entire field* for a few years.

Sigmoid is flat when you're far from the middle, and You're initializing it with relatively large numbers, try /1000.

So your abs-error (or square-error) is flat too, and the GradientDescent optimizer takes steps proportional to the slope.

Either of these should fix it:

Use [cross-entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) for the error - it's convex.

Use a better Optimizer, like [Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)
, who's step size is much less dependent on the slope. More on the consistency of the slope.

Bonus: Don't roll your own sigmoid, use [`tf.nn.sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid), you'll get a lot fewer NaN's that way.

Have fun!

Comment: That's an amazing answer, thanks! (I think I don't nead `mean(error)` since I don't use batches so there's nothing to average)